# can not run webapp with skinny war dependency in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, war

I have a maven web app project which has a dependency on a maven [skinny war project](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html).
Both projects, the main webapp and the skinny war project are in my eclipse.
Now when I run the main webapp in my original eclipse, where I built the projects, I can use my controllers from the skinny war project etc. 
Now I installed the same projects on a different eclipse on a different computer. I can run the main webapp but the controllers from the skinny war are not available.

There is a difference in the target folder of the project between my original eclipse and the other eclipse instance.

folders in target folder in original eclipse:

- m2e-wtp
- war
- ...

folder in target folder in new eclipse:

- m2e-wtp

Maybe it has something to do with this ?

Funny thing I found out.
When I close the project in eclipse, the controllers are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somebody has the same problem. I installed the following eclipse plugin. Even though I did not install this one on my original eclipse. But it works now.

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/